# Stop python timeout error

Tags: python-2.7, timeout

I have a code which is an infinite loop,i.e. it shouldnt stop working its entire lifetime

It is a code for controlling the traffic signal based on the density of road.So it should keep on calculating the density without timeout error.
As of now , i am able to calculate the density,but after about 10 loops,timeout error occurs

Comment: are you running this as web app ..? what exactly you are doing in the loop ..?  trying to get information from external sites ..?

Comment: in the loop i am just doing image processing to get the vehicle count in the road